# Selecting data using three tables only joining two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select data using three tables. I need to get an equity number and contract date from an actor and contract table where the name of the film = x from a film table.

I have done:

```
SELECT equity_number, contract_date
FROM actor,
     contract,
     film
WHERE actor.equity_number = contract.equity_number
  and title = 'x'
```

Although I am getting a column ambiguously defined error.

Comment: Qualify columns everywhere, like `contract.equity_number` instead of just `equity_number`.

Comment: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of those old, implicit comma separated joins.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for that, why is it that they have to be specified, whereas if I were using just the two tables I would get away without specifying the table before the attribute

Comment: If the same column name exists in two (or more) tables, you have to qualify those columns. (It's good practice to always qualifying all columns, in case of future table changes.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any Relationship with the film table.
And use a modern way of writing sql :)

```
SELECT a.equity_number, c.contract_date
FROM actor a
INNER JOIN contract c on a.equity_number = c.equity_number
INNER JOIN film f on f.SOMERELATIONSHIPID = c.SOMERELATIONSHIPID
WHERE f.title = 'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `JOINS` instead of old comma-separated syntax. After It set aliases for each table and use these aliases in select list. Something like:

```
SELECT a.equity_number, 
       c.contract_date
FROM actor a
LEFT JOIN contract c ON a.equity_number = c.equity_number
LEFT JOIN film f ON a.film_id = f.id -- there should be related columns 
          AND f.title = 'x'
```

Comment: That f.title condition in the WHERE clause makes the last LEFT JOIN execute as a regular inner join. Move to ON clause to get true left join behavior.

Comment: This query will throw errors.  In Oracle SQL the word AS is illegal between table names and table aliases.  It can be used (it is optional) between column names and their aliases.

Comment: @mathguy removed It, didn't noticed oracle tag.